# How can I make use of the class annotated with @grails.persistence.Entity in the jar

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

In my grails project, I want to use the domain class in the common jar file with the @grails.persistence.Entity annotation. but when I follow the step in the  [doc from grails site](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/hibernate.html#mappingWithHibernateAnnotations)

I add hibernate.cfg.xml which like

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping package="com.books" />
        <mapping class="com.books.Book" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

to grails-app/conf/hibernate/ directory.
but when I start the project, it report the error log:

```
2013-04-11 14:24:53,928 - org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader -20516 [pool-5-thread-1] ERROR  - Error executing bootstraps: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.baoxian.task.inscar.entity.QuoteTask.findById() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Long) values: [2851]
Possible solutions: find(), findAll(), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure), find(groovy.lang.Closure)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.baoxian.task.inscar.entity.QuoteTask.findById() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Long) values: [2851]
Possible solutions: find(), findAll(), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure), find(groovy.lang.Closure)
    at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:300)
    at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:293)
    at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:269)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.baoxian.task.inscar.entity.QuoteTask.findById() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Long) values: [2851]
Possible solutions: find(), findAll(), findAll(groovy.lang.Closure), find(groovy.lang.Closure)
    at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:22)
    ... 8 more
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:63383', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

It becomes obvious that the @Entity does not work.
besides, my BuildConfig.groovy likes:

```
compile ('com.baoxian:baoxian-task-inscar-manager:1.2.5-SNAPSHOT')
                {
                    excludes "org.grails", "org.slf4j", "xml-apis","mysql","org.hibernate","hsqldb","hibernate-annotations","org.quartz-scheduler","org.springframework"
                }
```

the com.baoxian:baoxian-task-inscar-manager:1.2.5-SNAPSHOT is just where my domain class from

it's the first time I ask question on the stackoverflow . ^_^

Comment: Where you put hibernate.cfg.xml?

Answer (score 1):

*Please someone correct me if I missed an easier/better solution for the problem.*

@yidao620c, I'm afraid that what you're doing will not work....

I recommend 2 solutions (For what you seem to want to do, I typically pick the second option):

1) **JPA entities annotations not Grails Entities annotations**

If you want to follow the docs, I believe that your JPA classes must reside inside the Grails project (JPA annotations, not grails *@Entity* annotations).

The easiest path for you might be the JPA plugin http://grails.org/JPA+Plugin. If you still want the dynamic finders, jump to option 2).

2) **Gorm ouside Grails to inject dynamic finders**

If you want to **import** grails annotated Entities from an external jar(non Grails project), you need to some extra steps to get the dynamic finders injected(*findAll*, etc.).

As it could be a long post with all the details, I will create a video soon about how to do it (Hints: http://www.grails.org/GORM+-+StandAlone+Gorm).

However, here's a short answer:

- Create a Groovy project (I typically use Gradle as build system for that).
- Have dependencies on Grails Gorm, Grails bootstrap and few
  others (slf4j, Spring, etc.)
- Have a Spring configuration (XML or Grails Spring DSL) to inject a Gorm Session factory. You can test quickly the dynamic finders with a simple main class -> load Spring Beans to setup Gorm -> Call domain objects using *withNewSession* or *withTransaction* or using Services.
- When you build your jar, the compilation phase will enhance your entities to inject the dynamic Gorm methods.

Comment: In my grails project, I want to use the class which is in the jar file. it's annotated by Entity.   but what you suggest is ouside Grails. not my need.  anyway， thanks a lot